# Fetch more than one column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I created a field that auto-complete when you enter a word part. It makes a query with mysql PDO . My request is made on the lastname of a patient. It works well.

Now, I'd like to display the firstname after the lastname.

My function is the following :

```
function searchForKeyword($keyword) {
    $db = connect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT lastname_patient, firstname_patient FROM `patients` WHERE lastname_patient LIKE ? ORDER BY lastname_patient");

    $keyword = $keyword . '%';
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);

    $isQueryOk = $stmt->execute();

    $results = array();

    if ($isQueryOk) {
      $results =$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    } else {
      trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $db = null; 

    return $results;
}
```

I think that the problem is with this line `$results =$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);` 
It fetch only one column.

How to change this to display the firstname of the patient after his lastname ?  (keeping the search by lastname)

Comment: `To return an array consisting of all values of a single column from the result set, specify PDO::FETCH_COLUMN. You can specify which column you want with the column-index parameter.` so why use `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`? Why not use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more effective to execute one fetch once.

```
$results = array();
if ($isQueryOk) {
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($result, $row['lastname_patient'].' '.$row['firstname_patient']);
      }
} else {
      trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try
     fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) instead of fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN).

PDO::FETCH_ASSOC will give you all result that you want in one associative array.

Answer (score 0):

Use CONCAT in your query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(lastname_patient, ', ', firstname_patient) as fullname 
FROM patients
WHERE lastname_patient LIKE ? 
ORDER BY lastname_patient
```